# Android ViewPager displays white screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm trying to create VeiwPager inside a Fragment using FragmentStatePagerAdapter.
it displays the first fragment but after scrolling to the second fragment there is just white fragment (even on scrolling back to the first fragment) 
I've tried to use PagerAdapter and set pictures without fragment but the result is same.

is there RAM problem ? what can I do to solve it?

Home fragment(contains ViewPager) :

```
private void initSlideShow(View view){
    VPImageSlider = (ViewPager16by9) view.findViewById(R.id.VPImageSlider);
    sliderDotsPanel = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.SliderDots);
    VPImageSliderAdapter vpImageSliderAdapter = new VPImageSliderAdapter(getFragmentManager());

    vpImageSliderAdapter.addSlide(R.drawable.dc_slide_1);
    vpImageSliderAdapter.addSlide(R.drawable.dc_slide_2);
    vpImageSliderAdapter.addSlide(R.drawable.dc_slide_3);
    vpImageSliderAdapter.addSlide(R.drawable.dc_slide_4);
    vpImageSliderAdapter.addSlide(R.drawable.dc_slide_5);

    VPImageSlider.setAdapter(vpImageSliderAdapter); 
}
```

ViewPager Fragment:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import iranelab.samsoft.net.iranelab.Classes.ImageView16by9;
import iranelab.samsoft.net.iranelab.R;


public class ViewPagerFragment extends Fragment {


private static final String ARG_PARAM4 = "imageTest";


private int imageTest;


public ViewPagerFragment() {}


public static ViewPagerFragment newInstance(String imageId, String type, String text,int imageTest) {
    ViewPagerFragment fragment = new ViewPagerFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_PARAM4, imageTest);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        imageTest = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PARAM4);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_pager, container, false);
    ImageView16by9 image = (ImageView16by9) view.findViewById(R.id.IVSlide);
    image.setImageResource(imageTest);
    return view;
}

}
```

ViewPager Adapter :

```
public class VPImageSliderAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private int[] slides = {};

public VPImageSliderAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
    super(fm);
}

public void addSlide(int drawable){
    slides = Arrays.copyOf(slides,slides.length+1);
    slides[slides.length-1]=drawable;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return slides.length;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return ViewPagerFragment.newInstance(slides[position]);
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
VPImageSliderAdapter vpImageSliderAdapter = new VPImageSliderAdapter(getFragmentManager());
```

to

```
VPImageSliderAdapter vpImageSliderAdapter = new VPImageSliderAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
```

it will work

Answer (score 1):

Just needed to add :

```
ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);
```